# Grammar for time zones- present or past tense?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, time, present-tense

Is there any emergent rule for verb tenses for dealing with action across time zones?

Today is 26 Jan in the US, but right now it is already 27 Jan in Australia. Do I, in the US, say "Today is Australia Day" or "Today *was* Australia Day"?

(Edited from comment, thanks Hank!)
The context was a casual conversation, brought up as (no offense to Australians) trivia or "Did you know?" facts. My location was in the US, where the day is not recognized, and at the time it was 27 Jan in Australia.

A 10th grade grammar textbook near at hand shed no light on the subject, neither was the topic mentioned by Miss Manners (on the chance it was solved by custom.)

Comment: Why would you say either? What is the context? Are you trying to say, "Today is tomorrow in Australia"?

Comment: Context: a casual conversation about current events. I had said "Today is Australia day." But right now it is not the 26th of January in Australia, where the day is recognized.

Comment: Please add it to the post, not everyone reads comments.

Comment: What is "Australia day"?

Comment: The national holiday, under a bit of controversy at the moment.

Comment: I think that answers my question then, if you want to convert it to an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I'll note that English grammar changes very slowly.  You basically (save for a few new idioms and technical words) cannot express anything today that you couldn't express 200 years ago.  And 200 years ago there were no timezones, and the fact that "today" was yesterday in Australia was irrelevant, since travel between there and the US/Europe took weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Today is the 26th where you currently reside, then the correct sentence would be:

> "Today is Australia Day"

**Today was Australia Day**, by itself, is contradictory; if *today* is the 27th, then *today* was never Australia Day. At that point, "*Yesterday* was Australia Day"

The only correct use of *was* would be "Today was Australia Day in 1987"

Comment: Actually, "Today was Australia Day in 1847" makes reasonable sense.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Also at 10:00pm at night after a day of celebration one might easily say, “today was Australia Day.”

Comment: At that point, "Today is still Australia Day"; I don't think "was" is necessary. Maybe "This day was Australia Day" (insinuating it is now night)